# Can't access Index.php in Controller

Tags: magento2, index, routes

For example in  My/Module/Controller/Index.php when I access https://website/module it won't work and I'll be redirected on 404 "Whoops, our bad..." page.

But if I use My/Module/Controller/Test/Index.php and access https://website/module/test it will properly work.

I want especially that url https://website/module and nothing else.

I'm probably missing something, it's been a while since I've been playing with Magento.

Thanks for your help

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you've missed the controller directory for your controller.

- Module path: eg `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule`
- Controller directory path: `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Controller`
- Assume you want to create a new controller named **Test**, the controller path for the Test controller: `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Controller/Test`
- The last one (the PHP class) is the action: `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Controller/Test/Index.php`

To achieve your need

> access your controller via url: MagentoBaseUrl/sampleurl

Take the following steps:

In the below example, assume **MyVendor** is the vendor name, **MyModule** is the module name.

1. Set frontName in routes.xml to “sampleurl”

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="yourmodule" frontName="sampleurl">
            <module name="MyVendor_MyModule" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

2. Create your controller file in this path: app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Index/Index.php

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly !

Comment: @Nagasaki glad to help!